# Copy constructor issue

Tags: c++, constructor

The program should resolve grade 1 equations in this specific manner. I had to use output messages for the constructors and destructors for better understanding of the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ec {  
public: float a, b;  //equation's parameters
public:
    Ec() {float x, y; cout <<"a= "; cin >> x; cout << "b= "; 
           cin >> y; a = x; b = y; cout << "void constr\n";};
    Ec(float x, float y) { a = x; b = y; cout << "param constr\n"; }
    ~Ec() { cout << "destr\n"; }
    Ec(Ec &z) { a = z.a; b = z.b; cout << "cpy constr\n"; }

friend float half1(Ec); //function to return a/2
friend float half2(Ec); //function to return b/2
friend float sol1(Ec);  //function to return the solution for the standard eq
friend float sol2(Ec);  //function to return the sol for the /2 param eq
};

float half1(Ec ec1) { return (ec1.a / 2);}
float half2(Ec ec1) { return (ec1.b / 2); }

float sol1(Ec ec1) { float x; return x = -ec1.b / ec1.a; }
float sol2(Ec ec1) { float x2; return x2 = -half2(ec1) / half1(ec1); }

int main()
{
    int x, y;
        cout << "a= ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "b= ";
        cin >> y;
        Ec ec1;
        Ec ec2(x, y);
        Ec ec3 = ec1;
 //the couts display for ex:" ec 2x+1=0 has sol -0.5"
        cout << "ec " << ec1.a << "x+ " << ec1.b << "=0 has sol " << sol1(ec1) << endl;
        cout << "ec " << ec2.a << "x+ " << ec2.b << "=0 has sol " << sol1(ec2) << endl;
        cout << "ec " << ec3.a << "x+ " << ec3.b << "=0 has sol " << sol1(ec3) << endl;

        cout << "ec halved " << half1(ec1) << "x+ " << half2(ec1) << "=0 has sol " << sol2(ec1) << endl;
        cout << "ec halved " << half1(ec2) << "x+ " << half2(ec2) << "=0 has sol " << sol2(ec2) << endl;
        cout << "ec halved " << half1(ec3) << "x+ " << half2(ec3) << "=0 has sol " << sol2(ec3) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have troubles understanding why after the first cpy constructor(for ec3) another cpy constructor is called then a destructor. What is it doing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your functions accept `Ec` by value, so copies are made to be passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions take `Ec` objects *by value*

```
float half1(Ec ec1) { return (ec1.a / 2);}
            ^
```

These will make function local *copies* that are then destroyed at the end of each function.

If you want to avoid making these copies, pass the arguments by const reference

```
float half1(Ec const& ec1) { return (ec1.a / 2);}
               ^
```